# How do I get the the last time a webform submission wizard page navigation button was clicked?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a need to know if a multipage webform submission has been edited, and when, by the current user. If I load the webform submission I can see when it was completed, updated or started, but I don't see how to know if there is an edit in process. This might happen when a person edits a page or 2 and leaves without getting all the way to the end and submitting the submission again.

```
    $completed = $submission->isCompleted();
    $changed_time = $submission->getChangedTime();
    $completed_time = $submission->getCompletedTime();
    $updated_time = $submission->getData()['timestamp'];
```

`$completed` shows if form was ever submitted.
`$changed_time` shows the last time the form action buttons were used, but after the first submit it only updates if the form is submitted again.
`$completed_time` shows the first time the form was submitted.
`$updated_time` shows the value in a field I added where I save the timestamp on the validation of any action button, but this is only available in the submission entity after a submit.

How can I get a real last edit time? Thanks.

Comment: If the submission hasn't been saved you won't know. But you could check out under Settings > Emails/Handlers of a webform you can configure an email getting triggered when a submission has been updated. Find out how Webform gets that information by looking into the Webform modules code.

Comment: The updated trigger seems to fire the same as the $changed_time above -- only when the form is submitted on the last page. Updated means resubmitted since the first submit. I need the intermediate page advances. I'm thinking about putting this in user data.

Comment: This, or is it maybe possible to add another submit handler to the "Next" button to let it store the current timestamp into a hidden webform field? But this means saving the whole submission. Which probably updates the updated timestamp anyways.